# Excluding rows from a query on a combination of mulitple conditions

Tags: postgresql

I want to drop rows from a query result based on the **combination of two columns** e.g.

**My table after join is**

```
-- JOIN of person and flag table based on person_id

Person.Person_id  Flag.Query_id  Flag.Person_id  Flag.query_flag
1                 10             1               IGNORED
1                 20             1               FAVORITE
2                 20             2               FAVORITE
2                 10             2               IGNORED 
3                 10             3               FAVORITE
```

Now, I want remove/drop all persons who have "ignored" the query 10.

So remove rows where `query_id = 10` and `flag = 'IGNORED'`.

**The resulting table should be:**

```
Person.Person_id  Flag.Query_id  Flag.Person_id  Flag.query_flag
1                 20             1               FAVORITE
2                 20             2               FAVORITE 
3                 10             3               FAVORITE
```

So I want to *drop* rows from the result based on the combination of two columns.

I know that I can *select* a row based on the combination of two columns as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  -- query with joins here
WHERE Flag.Query_id = 10 and Flag.query_flag = 'IGNORED'
```

I tried doing something like:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM  -- query with joins here
 WHERE NOT (Flag.Query_id = 10 AND Flag.query_flag = 'IGNORED')
```

I see here that `NOT` is applied to the columns individually and not to a combination of conditions.

How can I achieve my result without a subquery?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE NOT (Flag.Query_id = 10 and Flag.query_flag = 'IGNORED'); does not give the desired result. It drops all rows where query_id  = 10 even if the flag is "FAVORITE". It is not working on the combination of columns

Comment: Discussion **[moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77449/discussion-between-ypercube-and-gogogaga)**.

Comment: If you added table definitions showing data types and constraints, your actual query and your version of Postgres, this would actually be an very interesting question. Boolean logic with ROW values isn't trivial.

Answer (score 2):

To be precise, to ...

> remove rows where `query_id = 10` and `flag = 'IGNORED'`

... you need something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  ...  -- you are hiding a more complex query here!
WHERE (Flag.Query_id = 10 and Flag.query_flag = 'IGNORED') IS NOT TRUE;
```

In a `WHERE` clause, only `TRUE` qualifies. Rows with `FALSE` *or* `NULL` are excluded.

What you display:

```
...
WHERE NOT (Flag.Query_id = 10 and Flag.query_flag = 'IGNORED');
```

... would ***also*** exclude rows with `NULL` values in `Flag.Query_id` or `Flag.query_flag` - not exactly what you asked for. Even if the columns are defined `NOT NULL`, `NULL` values can be introduced with an `OUTER JOIN` or similar in your undisclosed query.

(The sample rows you display are not affected, since there are no `NULL` values.)